# Disappearing Line Trail on Mouse Hover?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, hover, gsap

I'm trying to create a line trail on hover, that follows your mouse.

So far, I've managed to create the line trail (in the codepen link here: https://codepen.io/johnellosit/pen/YzJLxPm).

But, I don't want it to be infinite - I'd like it to start overwriting itself/disappearing at a certain length.

How can I make that possible? (I'm very new to JS)

Here's a gif example!
https://imgur.com/a/9leH6qd